# How to add url link from java with css element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, location-href

Here is the code:

```
<span class='maincaptionsmall'>
Test
</span>
```

For some reasons of ajax and jquery codes in my page, I can't use HREF as Link, I mean, I can't use something like this following code:

```
<span class='maincaptionsmall'><a href="http://google.com">Test</a></span>
```

So, How can i use jquery to get this css element `maincaptionsmall` and it will set it to href link ?

Even I can't use `<div>` too, I should use everything as `<span>` Please give me an example that how to use jquery to set css element as href link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How's that you can't use a simple anchor? There's something really broken there that you should fix then instead of implementing workarounds, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

For getting `.maincaptionsmall` this DOM using jQuery use below code,

```
$('.maincaptionsmall')
```

and for wrapping innerText you can use `wrapInner`

```
$('.maincaptionsmall').wrapInner('<a href="http://google.com"></a>');
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tJWYH/)

**Edit**

You need to wrap code inside `document.ready` and also your document is not properly structured.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() // you are missing this
            {
                $('.maincaptionsmall').wrapInner('<a href="http://google.com"></a>');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class='maincaptionsmall'>Test</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please check this link and tell me what's the problem? [link]http://malayatourism.com/thisistest/test1.php

Comment: where is your jquery library file attache the jquery library jquery.js in malayatourism.com/thisistest/test1.php

Comment: I used this library <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  , can you pls check it again?

Comment: It doesnt work, I used these two: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: ohh yeah, you are right, I missed that one, thanks buddy, IT IS WORKING VERY GOOD ..... THANK YOU SOO MUCH... :-)

Comment: I used it into my page, actually again it doesn't work, maybe cause of another JS files inside of page, even If I will remove one of them, page wont load, however your code is working well. but still I couldn't solve my problem. is there another way that i will be able to use it ?

Comment: Please check this link [link]http://malayatourism.com/thisistest/testnow/index.php  really sorry to disturb you, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Amin add this code into `slides2.css` file `.maincaptionsmall a { position: relative;z-index: 99999; }`  and see

Comment: yes, GREAT JOB ... you are really professional. its done.. working perfectly... thank you so so so so so much... with warm regards.. :-)